# psql: command not found when running bash script in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, postgresql, maven

I'm writing a Java method to run a local bash script using Eclipse. The code is showing as below:

```
public static void setUp() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p;
        String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        filePath = filePath.concat("/path/to/the/script");
        String command = String.format("sh %s/setUp.sh", filePath);
        System.out.println(command);
        try {
            p = rt.exec(command);
            final int errorValue = p.waitFor();
            if (errorValue != 0) {
                System.out.println("error detected!");
                InputStream error = p.getErrorStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(error));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                p.destroy();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

AND the bash file is very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
#create a local db and import some data
createdb -U dummy -O dummy -h localhost dbname
psql -h localhost -d dbname --file $1
```

## The issue is

```
line 4: createdb: command not found
line 5: psql: command not found
```

I can run the script in terminal and I can copy line4 and line5 in terminal, and I can run mvn exec command in the terminal to run the method. All works.

## Only thing not working is it was executed in eclipse.

I'm open to any opinion or advices, please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks for all the helps in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the `Runtime` that is used to execute the script won't have the paths set correctly. Try using full paths for the commands in the script, and see if that works (you can find the full paths by running `which createdb` and `which psql` in the terminal).